# instructions for Facebook Like- Button

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have the following problem. I am trying to create a like button for my facebook page, but I got stuck. I followed the instructions but it's not working! I did nowhere see a value to set the coordinates of this button. Where is it? thanks

**EDIT2:** I edited it again, now, the first onActivityResult has this problem:

void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityresult

what is wrong?

**main activity:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import ch.OptiLab.visuscontroll.R;

import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.widget.LikeView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {




//UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
TextView textView;
//  Button buttonende;
    Button tipps;
        Button btn1;
        Button rate;

    LikeView LikeView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
      tipps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tipps);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSTART);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        rate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate);
        rate.setOnClickListener(this);
        AppRater.app_launched(this);

        Settings.sdkInitialize(this);
        LikeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.LikeView);
        LikeView.setObjectId("http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/");


       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

         likeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }



 tipps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
            builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                   .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);

            // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }




       });
    }

    protected Context getActivity() {

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Easteregg lololol", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,VisusActivity.class), 0);

    }







    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == R.drawable.v1)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.nopercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v2)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tenpercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v3)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.twentypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v4)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.thirtypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v5)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.fourtypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v6)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.fiftypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v7)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.sixtypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v8)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.seventypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v9)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.eightypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v10)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.ninetypercent));
        else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v11)textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.onehundretpercent));



    }   
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();

      // Logs 'install' and 'app activate' App Events.

    }
```

**xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ch.OptiLab.visustest.MainActivity" >



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="@string/Text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSTART"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonende"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="@string/beenden" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tipps"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSTART"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:text="@string/tipps_tricks" />

    <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
 android:id="@+id/LikeView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/tipps"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginTop="29dp" >
```

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML code?

Comment: of course! as you can see, there is a 'like_view' button. I added it with the hope, it would work this way.

Comment: Also, can you define what "It's not working" means? Please be as specific as you can.

Comment: at the uiHelper = new (...)  , it says, callback can not be resolved to a variable. And at the protected void onActivityResult(...) , it says the variable is duplicated(I used it another time below, edited code in question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

void is an invalid type for the variable `onActivityresult` occure because you are using  `onActivityresult` method inside `onCreate` method. remove this method from onCreate and call

> likeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

from your `onActivityResult` method. Also check your LikeView variable name it should be same everywhere you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues implementing LikeView until I upgraded the Facebook API from 3.18 to 3.20.

Also, you can't use a regular button.  You need to use the Facebook LikeView widget like this:

```
    <com.facebook.widget.LikeView
        android:id="@+id/lvLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

Comment: thank you, that was also wrong at the code. but, please, have a look at the question now.

Comment: Are you getting the same errors as before, or different?  Build time or run time errors?

Have you set up your key hashes (detailed in Facebook API guide)

Have you set up your manifest with the applicationID?

Comment: I set up my key hashes. don't exactly know what you mean with the applicationID. LikeButton appears, but when I click it, nothing happens.