# Cannot resolve symbol for facebook likeView

Tags: android, facebook-like

package com.example.user.likebutton;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.widget.LikeView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "FBLike";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // To initialize Facebook SDK in your app
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
        // Get LikeView button
        LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
        // Set the object for which you want to get likes from your users (Photo, Link or even your FB Fan page)
        likeView.setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/tomatojuice");
        // Set foreground color fpr Like count text
        likeView.setForegroundColor(-256);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        LikeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.i(TAG, "OnActivityResult...");
    }
}
```

I cannot resolve symbol for

```
LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view); (LikeView)
likeView.setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/tomatojuice"); (SetObjectID)
likeView.setForegroundColor(-256); (setForegroundColor)
```

and i cant seem to import this file
import com.facebook.widget.LikeView;

Mind tell me anything that i forgot to add?i already put repositories mavenCentral() inside repository and put the facebook sdk  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'for dependency

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852071/instructions-for-facebook-like-button

Comment: use `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'`

Comment: add the facebook 4.7.9 dependency and i still having the same problem.

Comment: please help me anyone